# Google Play Service not getting updated latest version in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-sdk-manager

I am developing location based native Android application. I am using the play service version around 10 series. I heard there are lot of release of play services done by Google. I need to use the latest play service versions like 11 series or 12. I am trying to update the latest play service version through my Android studio SDK Manager. But there is no update occurred in this update. Showing 11.0.4 my top most version of the play service. How to update my play service version upto 12. I referred the versions from here.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

My current play service version is showing as 48 in SDK Manager. How can I update latest version. There is no more update available. Help from anyone is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the google play services libraries **are not** in the SDK Manager.
You can donwload the latest dependencies directly from maven.google.com.

Check the [official doc:](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

- Add the libraries under the `dependencies` block
- **Ensure that your top-level `build.gradle` contains a reference to the `google()` repo or to `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`**.